# Psfrag in LaTeX using Overleaf pdflatex compiler

Tags: overleaf, psfrag, pstool

**I can** get psfrag to work in the Overleaf **LaTeX compiler**.

And the code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \psfrag{F}[c][c][1][0]{$F$}
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{root/Force.eps}
\end{figure}
```

**But I can't** get psfrag to work in **Overleaf pdflatex compiler**.

These are the packages I am using:

```
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{psfrag}
```

and the code in my design.tex file:

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{root/Force.eps}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \psfragfig[mode=nonstop]{root/Force}{
  \psfrag{F}[c][c][1][0]{$F$}
  }
\end{center}
```

**Error:** Package pstool Warning: No file "root/Force.tex" or "root/Force-psfrag.tex" can be found that may contain macros for "root/Force.eps" on input line 27.

**Log:**

Package pstool Warning: No file "root/Force.tex" or "root/Force-psfrag.tex" can be found that may contain macros for "root/Force.eps" on input line 27.

File: root/Force.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<root/Force.eps>

Comment: please don't post disconnected fragments we can't test, using psfrag with pdflatex can never really work `pstool` simply uses latex in the background and includes the resulting pdf. (`% !TeX --shell-escape` comments do nothing at overleaf, they are simply comments)

Comment: what does `not work` mean? do you get an error or warning in the log?

Comment: `\psfrag{F}{%F%}}`  is `\psfrag{F}{` as the `%` is  a comment. What psfrag replacement did you intend?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes you are right % !TeX --shell-escape did nothing, I removed it. I updated the code and inserted error logs.

Comment: overleaf uses `--output-directory` which complicates these things, try putting the eps in your main folder and use `{Force.eps}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Unfortunately. I have not seen any working examples of it in Overleaf. I am giving up on it.