psfrag using Overleaf and pdflatex compiler
I can't get psfrag to work using Overleaf and pdflatex as compiler.
I'm using these packages:
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{psfrag}

And this is how I create my figure:
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\psfrag{ax1xlabel}{$x$}
\psfrag{ax1ylabel}{$y$} 
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/test_fig.eps}
\end{figure}

However, the intended label replacements are not performed.
EDIT:
I tested @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz solution (the template she linked) but no success. The labels just don't change.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\psfragfig[]{plot_try}{%
    \psfrag{xlabeltest}{$x$} % Replace xlabel with your x-axis label
    \psfrag{ylabeltest}{$y$} % Replace ylabel with your y-axis label
}
\end{figure}

plot_try is an .eps figure, a simple x,y plot with the xlabel named 'xlabeltest' and the ylabel named 'ylabeltest'. I tested this code on the template he linked
EDIT 2:
Tested Marijn solution:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}

This is how I create my figure:
\begin{figure}[h!tb]
\centering
\psfrag{xlabeltest}{$x$}
\psfrag{ylabeltest}{$y$}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{plot_try.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

It doesn't do the replacement unfortunately. I inspected the .eps file and the labels text looks just normal:
131.7 -21.4 Td
/F9_0 16.5 Tf
(xlabeltest)
[7.6065
0
and for ylabel:
0 0 Td
/F9_0 16.5 Tf
(ylabeltest)
[7.6065
0
I also implemented the second solution (using pstool) like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstool}
\begin{document}

This is how I create my figure:
\begin{figure}[h!tb]
\centering
\psfragfig[width=0.6\linewidth]{plot_try}{
\psfrag{xlabeltest}{$x$}
\psfrag{ylabeltest}{$y$}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

This gives me a warning:
Package pstool Warning: No file "plot_try.tex" or "plot_try-psfrag.tex" can be found that may contain macros for "plot_try.eps"

Maybe https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/getting-psfrag-to-work-in-pdflatex/twtwrxfjrhfg can help

psfrag doesn't work with pdflatex (it needs postscript), looking at the pstool documentation it can do some support for pdflatex by calling latex in the background, but it uses its own command syntax not \psfrag directly. But if using psfrag it is simpler to use latex.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for your answer, I have already gone through that document but still no luck.

@DavidCarlisle thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I need to use pdflatex. Then I assume there is no way psfrag will work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@floyd123 you need to use pstools syntax if you want to use pstools, but all that is doing is taking out the figure, running it with latex and psfrag than including it back via \includegraphics so you can do that directly if you prefer

@DavidCarlisle I just found your answer to a related question here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678258/psfrag-in-latex-using-overleaf-pdflatex-compiler?newreg=8c17395019fb4306ae950387ae5a215b
Tried that, but still no luck. Apparently it just doesn't work on Overleaf

sam carter has already linked to specific overleaf instructions above, overleaf hosts a standard texlive 2023, it will work on overleaf, but you have not shown any document that can be tested, and if using pdftool it needs to use pdftool not psfrag commands,

@DavidCarlisle I just edited my question. Tried sam carter template but no success

https://www.overleaf.com/read/wjhvxxkpfqpn#ca2a46 seems to work.

There are two ways for using psfrag with pdfLaTeX. Both of them work in Overleaf.
The first way is to use psfrag in the 'classical' way, so first the \psfrag substitution commands and then \includegraphics. This is the way that resembles most closely the (incomplete) example in the question. This way however does not work with pstool. For this to work you need the package auto-pst-pdf that takes care of collecting the PostScript parts and performing an extra latex-dvips-ps2pdf run.
MWE with the following EPS file (created in Inkscape for this example):

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
This is how I create my figure:
\begin{figure}[h!tb]
\centering
\psfrag{ax1xlabel}{$x$}
\psfrag{ax1ylabel}{$y$}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{figures/test_fig.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Result in Overleaf:


Alternatively, you can use pstool. However, the syntax is a bit different, as explained (poorly) in the pstool manual and also explained (a bit better, but still not very clearly) on the linked Overleaf help page. The syntax is that you use the command \psfragfig[width=0.6\linewidth]{figures/test_fig}{} with as last argument all the \psfrag commands. You don't use \includegraphics in this case. Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstool}
\begin{document}
This is how I create my figure:
\begin{figure}[h!tb]
\centering
\psfragfig[width=0.6\linewidth]{figures/test_fig}{
\psfrag{ax1xlabel}{$x$}
\psfrag{ax1ylabel}{$y$}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

The result is the same as above.

Note that sometimes the substitution does not work even when using the right syntax. This is usually caused by the text not being represented properly in the EPS file. Either the text has been converted to curves by the program that created the EPS, or it is still text but the individual characters (or small groups of characters) may be represented in a discontinuous way. For example, the original text in the example figure in this answer looks as follows in the EPS source:
BT
9.999978 0 0 -9.999978 149.840723 353.369989 Tm
/f-0-0 1 Tf
(ax1xlabel)Tj
9.63471 8.128927 Td
(ax1ylabel)Tj
ET

Here the labels are preserved fully, so they can be replaced. But sometimes an exporting program may turn this into (ax)(1x)(lab)(el) or something, which looks fine when printing or viewing the figure on screen (or when converting it to pdf for example) but it causes the replacement by psfrag to fail.
In this case your options are to use shorter labels (to hopefully avoid the issue), or to examine the export options in the program that produces the EPS to see if you can get cleaner output, or to edit the EPS file manually to patch the labels together, or to use a workaround solution, for example to produce the figure without the text in the original program and then add the text later either directly in LaTeX or using Inkscape which has options to produce LaTeX code for the desired output.

Hi, thank you for your answer. I tested both your solutions but no success. I added further details in my question

@floyd123 maybe you can make your test project on Overleaf available via link sharing? Then I can take a look at your actual code and files.

Sure, here it is https://www.overleaf.com/9693236857dmmjvgnswcvz#dff499

@floyd123 I tried it out, it's actually a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289048/cant-get-psfrag-to-replace-text-in-pdf. I don't have time now but I will try to add this to my answer later.

Thank you! I tested that solution and it looks like it is doing something. I updated the shared code the modified .eps file and new code. The only thing is that the new y label doesn't get positioned correctly

@floyd123 you can rotate it with \psfrag{ylabeltest}{\rotatebox{180}{$y$}}.

Thank you very much! I accepted your answer
